# Integration Testing of secure Spring Web Service

Tags: integration-testing, spring-ws, ws-security

I am trying to write server side integration tests of my Spring Web Service Endpoint secured using 
- Spring WS Security 2.1.2.RELEASE and
- WSS4j 1.6.9.
I am trying to follow Spring documentation http://static.springsource.org/spring-ws/sites/2.0/reference/html/server.html. With the setup that I have got so far, I can send a request payload

```
<myns:MyRequest xmlns:myns="...">
        ...
</myns:MyRequest>
```

using MockWebServiceClient as

```
mockWebServiceClient.sendRequest(withPayload(requestPayload)).andExpect(clientOrSenderFault());
```

which the integration test properly maps to the endpoint in the test context and I get a "Could not validate request: No WS-Security header found" error as expected.

**Problem:** Now the problem here is if I send a request in a SOAP envelope with a security header and body, I would get an endpoint not found exception.

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:myns="...">
   <soapenv:Header>
       ...
   </soapenv:Header>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <myns:MyRequest>
        ...
      </myns:MyRequest>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

since it will try to find an endpoint around "{http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/}Envelope".

Is there a way to work around this problem?

Comment: The newer version of Spring WS Test which is 2.1 has two methods added in RequestCreaters: RequestCreator withSoapEnvelope(Source soapEnvelope) and RequestCreator withSoapEnvelope(Resource soapEnvelope) which I can use to send SOAP envelopes for Integration testing. http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?135298-Integration-Testing-of-secure-Spring-Web-Service

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The newer version of Spring WS Test which is 2.1 has two methods added in RequestCreaters: RequestCreators.withSoapEnvelope(Source soapEnvelope) and RequestCreators.withSoapEnvelope(Resource soapEnvelope) which allow sending SOAP envelopes for Integration testing. http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?135298-Integration-Testing-of-secure-Spring-Web-Service